# Incorrect placement of SELECT in a cursor causes countless amount of tables pop up

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, temp-tables

I've been busy with coding a stored procedure which contains two temporary tables and a cursor. It's been two days since I've received this assignment and it's giving me a hard time, for it's the first time I'm busy with coding an SP of such complexity.

The cursor is supposed to derive data from DATABASE_X, and lets that data being fetched for making comparisons with DATABASE_Y.

The **TableInfo** table in **DATABASE_Y** is to contain all, or most of the schemas and tables that are in **DATABASE_X**. The similar thing goes for the **ColumnInfo** table as well, with the only difference from the **TableInfo** table being able to contain the column data as well.

The temporary tables, which respectively contain the data of the non-existing tables in **DATABASE_Y.TableInfo** and the non-existing columns in **DATABASE_Y.ColumnInfo** are meant to be filled after the comparisons. (non-existing means that the table A exists in DBX but not in the rows of DBY.TableInfo, and vice versa for the case of columns)

The **NotInUse** column that exists in DATABASE_Y.TableInfo is a determinant for whether a table in DBX should be considered to be examined.

```
CREATE TABLE #NONEXISTENT_TABLES(
    SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE #NONEXISTENT_COLUMNS(
    SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)

USE DATABASE_X;
DECLARE CRS_GET_NONEXISTENT_STUFF CURSOR FOR
        select s.name as 'sname', t.name as 'tname', c.name as 'cname'
        from sys.schemas (nolock) s
        join sys.tables (nolock) t 
            on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
        join sys.columns (nolock) c 
            on c.object_id = t.object_id
        order by 1,2,3
OPEN CRS_GET_NONEXISTENT_STUFF

FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_GET_NONEXISTENT_STUFF INTO @SchemaName,
                                                 @TableName,
                                                 @ColumnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    select @SchemaName, @TableName
    from DATABASE_Y..TableInfo (nolock) ti
    print @SchemaName + '-' + @TableName
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
    BEGIN
        declare @NotInUse varchar(100)
        select @NotInUse = ti.[NotInUse]
        from DATABASE_Y..TableInfo (nolock) ti
        where ti.[Schema] = @SchemaName
        and ti.[Name] = @TableName
        print @SchemaName + '-' + @TableName
        IF @NotInUse = '0'
        DECLARE @colname varchar(100)
        BEGIN
            select @colname = ci.[Name]
            from DATABASE_Y..ColumnInfo (nolock) ci
            where ci.[TableSchema] = @SchemaName
            and ci.[TableName] = @TableName
            and ci.[Name] = @ColumnName
            print @SchemaName + '-' + @TableName + '-' + @ColumnName
            IF @colname IS NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #NONEXISTENT_COLUMNS(SEMA_ADI, TABLO_ADI, KOLON_ADI)
                VALUES(@SchemaName, @TableName, @colname)
            END
        END
    END
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO #NONEXISTENT_TABLES(SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME)
        VALUES (@SchemaName, @TableName)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_GET_NONEXISTENT_STUFF INTO @SchemaName,
                                                 @TableName,
                                                 @ColumnName
END

CLOSE CRS_GET_NONEXISTENT_STUFF
DEALLOCATE CRS_GET_NONEXISTENT_STUFF

SELECT * FROM #NONEXISTENT_COLUMNS

SELECT * FROM #NONEXISTENT_TABLES


DROP TABLE #NONEXISTENT_COLUMNS


DROP TABLE #NONEXISTENT_TABLES
```

Assuming that:
     *The first schema on DBX is AAA and the first table on DBX of AAA is BBBBB
     *The second table of AAA is CCCCC;

I receive a countless amount of tables as the result of a hardly-looks-like-it-would-end-quickly query, having only AAA-BBBBB displayed in 5-6 tables with around 5000 rows, then moving onto AAA-CCCCC doing what happened above, and it goes on and on.

I believe that my mistake was to put the SELECT commands under that WHILE loop, but I also believe that it wasn't my only mistake...

I'd appreciate having the advices of all of you about this issue.

I apologize for the mere wall of text.

Comment: An error at script above causes me to receive an infinite amount of tables and I have to solve that issue... that's basically the question.

I should only receive two final tables which are the tables of the non existing columns and the non existing tables.

Comment: Well remove / comment enough code that you figure out why it's stuck, and once you know what causes it, fix it.

Comment: I felt like I should post the entire code because I'm not that familiar with the syntax... I'm not sure whether if I have more than one mistakes or not.

Comment: Although I wonder how that can even work since the statement in your if is declare, and then begin is the next statement

Comment: Well just posting your code here and asking us to debug it is clearly off-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'll try do divide the code and will try to minimize the amount of text at the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would suggest is to read this article - [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

The next thing is that for each loop you run this:

```
select @SchemaName, @TableName
from DATABASE_Y..TableInfo (nolock) ti;

print @SchemaName + '-' + @TableName;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
....
```

I have added line breaks and statement terminators for clarity, but the first select is why you are getting loads of results sets. This does nothing and will run for every column in your database. Also where you have `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1` it will always return 0 because it follows a print command, which returns no rows. So you will never enter the "true" section of this `IF/ELSE` block.

I am quite certain that you don't need a cursor at all, and as a general rule unless you absolutely have to use a cursor you should not use one. So I think you can simply replace all your loops with two set based inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE #NONEXISTENT_TABLES(
    SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    object_id INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #NONEXISTENT_COLUMNS(
    SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT #NONEXISTENT_TABLES (SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME, objecobject_idt_ID)
SELECT  s.name, t.Name, object_id
FROM    sys.tables AS t
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
            ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    DATABASE_Y..TableInfo AS ti
            WHERE   ti.TableSchema = s.Name
            AND     ti.name = t.name
            --AND       ti.NotInUse = 0
        );

INSERT #NONEXISTENT_COLUMNS (SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)      
SELECT  nt.SCHEMA_NAME, nt.TABLE_NAME, c.name
FROM    sys.columns AS c
        INNER JOIN #NONEXISTENT_TABLES AS nt 
            ON nt.object_id = c.object_id);
```

Comment: Should probably be `NOT EXISTS` since they want the ones that aren't in TableInfo, but definitely no need to use a cursor for this.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yeah, I think you are right, I was struggling to pick up the intent from the original post. Having re-read this, I have edited as per your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: My instructor especially wanted me to do it with cursors in order to make me have an idea about both the temptables & cursors.

Nevertheless, I really do appreciate your reply and will begin examining it ASAP.